# Converting Positive Value to Negative Value and storing Access Table

Tags: ms-access-2010, negative-number

I am new to VB.Net and Access. I am trying to Capture value in TextBox and then convert it to Negative and store it in the DB.
Whatever I do it still stores the value in the Positive Integer.

Thanks in Advance

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form3

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim connString As String
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\neetals\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xx\xx\DailyTotal.mdb"
    Dim xAmt As Integer
    xAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmt.Text)

    xAmt = (xAmt * -1)



    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAmt.Text) Then

        MsgBox("Amount Value Cannot be Empty")

    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNotes.Text) Then

        MsgBox("Notes Cannot be Empty")

    Else


        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xdate", DateTimePicker1)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xAmt", txtAmt.Text)
        sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", txtNotes.Text)

        Try


            sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
            sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
            sqlconn.Open()
            sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cash(cdate, cAmt, cNotes) VALUES(@xdate,@xAmt, @note)"

            'Math.Abs(-xAmt)




            sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlconn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)


        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You calculate your value...

```
xAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmt.Text)
xAmt = (xAmt * -1)
```

but then you don't use the `xAmt` variable, but the textbox again (which still has the original value):

```
sqlquery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xAmt", txtAmt.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, As i told you that I"M NEW to VB.Net. How do i bind the  textbox to Field in the Table ???